# Recursive index signature in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add index signature typings to a nested object so I can access some of its properties via computed values.

For example, given this object:

```js
export const english = {
  home: {
    title: 'Title',
    characters_list: 'Characters list',
    moves: 'Moves',
    header: 'Home',
    search: 'Search',
  },
  character: {
    detail: {
      about: {
        title: 'About',
        info: 'Info',
        full_name: 'Full name',
        status: 'Status',
        gender: 'Gender',
      },
      origin: {
        title: 'Origin',
        origin: 'Origin',
        current_location: 'Current location',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I'd like to access its properties like this:

```js
const key = 'moves';
english.home[key]
```

But I can't get it right. So far I've been able to type the first layer

```js
export type Translation = {
    [key: string]: typeof english[keyof typeof english]
}
```

I think this needs some sort of recursive approach, but I have no idea how to implement it

Comment: What are the dynamic parts of the object's shape? Is the object structure the same across translations? Accessing `english.home[key]` should work as long as `key` is a const.

Comment: It does work in runtime, but I get TypeScript errors stating that 'string' is not an index of my object. Different languages shoud have the same structure, yes. The object is constant in shape and content, but in some cases I need to use a computed key instead of accessing directly to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I know what we need to do. The problem is that objects allow keys to be of every value in type `string`, but once you define a type, you work with a subset of `string`. Hence TypeScript throws -- rightfully so -- an error that you can't just access with *every* string, but only the strings that are valid keys (e.g. `moves`, `title`, etc.)

So, at one point in time, you have to make sure that the key you want to access is valid.

Here are the possibilities

**a) A string literal w const context**

The moment you assign

```
const key = 'moves'
```

`key` is not of type `string`, but of type `'moves'`, a very specific value type (or literal type) and sub-type of `string`. This access should work

```
const key = 'moves'
english.home[key] //
```

Alternatively, define them `as const` to get the same effect

```
let key = 'moves' as const // also 'moves', not string
```

Same behavior with a generic pick function

```
function pick<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, k: K) {
  return o[k]
}
pick(english.home, 'moves')
pick(english, 'home')
pick(pick(english, 'home'), 'moves')
```

This is basically the same as direct property access, but you let the generic constraints help you finding the right types.

**b) Type predicates to narrow down**

But you are not working with string literals, you work with computed keys. Which means you have to somehow come from the big set of strings to the smaller set of actual keys. You can do this with a function that checks if this key is valid (which you should do anyway), and a type predicate to narrow down the type in control flow (you see what that is in a second)

So imagine a helper function like this:

```
function isKeyOf<O extends Object>(o: O, k: string | number | symbol): k is keyof O {
  return typeof k === "string" && Object.keys(o).indexOf(k) >= 0
}
```

There is a lot going on in this function.

1. We define a generic called O which is constraint by being an Object
2. We allow a key `k` passed in which can be of all possible object key types
3. We then check if it's a proper string property accessor and if it's in the list of keys. If so, we can safely say that k is of type `keyof O`

Type predicates work for functions that return a boolean value. If this condition is true, then the type becomes something different (namely, `keyof O`)

You can use this to create a `pickSafe` function, where you can pass any key

```
function pickSafe<T extends Object>(o: T, k: string) {
  if (isKeyOf(o, k)) {
    return o[k]
  }
  throw new Error('Not accessible')
}


pickSafe(english.home, 'moves')
pickSafe(english, 'home')
pickSafe(pickSafe(english, 'home'), 'moves')
```

The problem is, that while this access works, you lose information on the object you are accessing. You would need to do runtime type-checks, then. Do

```
const res = pickSafe(english, 'home')
```

.. and hover over `res`, you see what possible types can come out of this

This is actually desired behavior, as it tells you the places in your app where things can get unclear.

If you really know that your app works and computed keys are what they are, you can always do a type-cast to override the uncertainty of TypeScript

```
const keyey = myRandomString as keyof typeof english.home
pick(english.home, keyey)
```

Here's a playground for you to [fiddle around](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=7&ssl=40&ssc=26&pln=39&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72Mg5gGwJaoAWcAvHAN4BQcchEAtsAFwXU1wx4w7NwDkAFS48%20AGjY0EhAIZRpCGMCioA%20vnQs%20AYRlyFS1HHUwxEuPQgA3YKk0BZKzdPtawaQBMlmgBINgz9lQ3KClNAGVgqQCAX3FJXXlFKBYqF08YaTwcFLMaaQAjCABXGByXF05uXj4AQUKSgPK4PGQAMwhNAEk2iEby1qKcHBVkaUZNADFBnDhRxj6XdGkYItt%20MIyV1AX2LExPZP4AcX2lHdjcuGg8LBaypo5haoB5KBuWnZpr2%20RNV-fkJ9EEUoFBMDA1BAEMs8ChNFoQWDkPAcFCYShznF2BcaBdopRKDAAJ5gYBwARyNA4dHIUgcEnACCtOCYXAEQgEgbIBSw2lgPAIADWAB4BCyQIpkO5DM98gArYAKURwADS4sl0rgguARKZ5IAfAAKDrk5WClgqgCUrBoYJWUFpEAA2oKALqUfGUTwIalgxAodDmIkAJWkUoYGze2BY6CjWAJ-KFhtZ6kIADo6IxlXwLNZtpbKInBcnsKns5n-AWi4bqyn2eW-HxLdnc04C5QkGh4NqiTq6fQQ2H3BGYHG4NJDD29cTSXq60QM35CwLi-P0xWzTqde2uTyUM1UCqdc9WsLnur9jL5YqYEaTc8zTHRy0sHAAD6zIr0fJKd9wVBEt%20EA4JaLCCgeWo6nq56pHAdogrSM6Msy4EkGhcAAESxi%20GFwAAZHhcCygqChpj2qDGpaaYtJ4IAnoagrWvqZAAAwepyRTcpw%205FmE0itMAooXlKV4kbexosAIj7-s%202DWrBeDMoaBBHkS9EQGalryWY8EOlcLruribAwIQUAQAA7rMwCWQAoqC0CGnwAByEDwPICA2KgeD5CIBaesuQp8QJJZsguG78K2%20YBYKQXACFZb8BWTbRbFNYrqla4NvMzYRY4%20ZAA).

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple javascript function reduce

```js
const key = 'home.moves';

const value = key.split('.').reduce((obj,prop) => obj[prop], english);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks!

I guess that would work too, and so would `(english.home as any)[key]`, but I'd like the whole object tree to have the id signature typing to avoid these workarounds